# GPU memory not released tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, memory-leaks

I have the issue that my GPU memory is not released after closing a tensorflow session in Python. These three line suffice to cause the problem:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
sess=tf.Session() 
sess.close()
```

After the third line the memory is not released. I have been up and down many forums and tried all sorts of suggestions, but nothing has worked for me. For details please also see my comment at the bottom here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19731

Here I have documented the ways in which I mange to kill the process and thus release the memory, but this is not useful for long-running and automated processes. I would very much appreciate any further suggestions to try. I am using Windows.

EDIT: I have now found a solution that at least allows me to do what I am trying to do. I am still **NOT** able to release the memory, but I am able to 'reuse' it. The code has this structure:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
cfg=K.tf.ConfigProto()
#cfg.gpu_options.allow_growth=True #this is optional
cfg.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.8 #you can use any percentage here

#upload your data and define your model (2 layers in this case) here    

for i in range(len(neuron1)):
    for j in range(len(neuron2)):
        K.set_session(K.tf.Session(config=cfg))
        #train your NN for i,j
```

The first time the script enters the loop the GPU memory is still allocated (80% in the above example) and thus cluttered, however this code nonetheless seems to reuse the same memory somehow. I reckon the `K.set_session(K.tf.Session(config=cfg))` somehow destorys or resets the old session allowing the memory to be 'reused' within this context at least. Note that I am **not** using `sess.close()` or `K.clear_session()` or resetting the default graph explicitly. This still does not work for me. When done with the loops the GPU memory is still full.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17048#issuecomment-367948448) discussion. You can reuse your allocated memory but if you want to free the memory, then you would have to exit the Python interpreter itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was aware of the post, but somehow from other posts gathered, that other users do manage to free the memory using `close.sess()` and similar... Strange that it is not possible. All due to the risk of fragmentation as mentioned on the tf webiste I guess?

Comment: Yeah seems like it is a design decision from their part!

Comment: This has *really* put me in a bad spot.  When trying to develop an app, I can't start a session that loads a NN, runs a while, kill that session, and then start a new session with a different NN.  I now have to build a client application (with it's own process) that I can launch from my main app.  This client app runs the NN.  When I'm done with it, I kill that client, and can later re-spawn it with a different NN.  All this complication (including the needed interprocess communications) because I can't force TF to release the GPU memory that I know it no longer needs.  What a pain.

Comment: Yeah this seems to be a really glaring problem that I am not sure there is going to be any fix. Did you try [this gist](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17048#issuecomment-441155627) from the discussion to see if it is helpful in any way?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, it should be as simple as:

`from numba import cuda`

`cuda.close()`